# Times of free-fall in different inertial reference frames in classical physics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, inertial-frames, free-fall

Imagine that a ball is thrown directly down at a rate of 20 m/s from a height of 100m in Earth's gravitational field. If we were to calculate the time it takes to fall we could use the kinematic equation to get 100m = (20m/s)t + 1/2(9.8m/s^2)t^2 and solving the quadratic equation we would get t = 2.916s.

Now imagine that we were in a reference frame moving down at 20 m/s. In that reference frame we could say that 100m = 1/2(9.8m/s^2)t^2 since the ball is falling from rest in that frame. We then get t = 4.512s. But in classical physics, isn't time a universal constant in all inertial reference frames? Then why do we get different times?

Sorry if this sounds stupid but I actually don't get it.

Comment: You probably mean non-relativistic physics. "Classical" contrasts with "quantum", not with relativistic. General Relativity is a classical theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're describing the same physical process using two points of view, in this case two reference systems. Physical processes must be invariant w.r.t. the reference systems, coordinates or parameterization you use to describe it. So, you are right to guess that there is a flaw in your description.

And the flaw is that when you're in the moving reference frame, you see the ground approaching you at $20 \, m/s$. So, to find the time when the ball hits the ground is the solution of the equation

$100 \, m - 20 \, m/s \cdot t = \dfrac{1}{2} g t^2$,

that is exactly the same equation you wrote in the fixed reference frame, taking the term $20 \, m/s \cdot t$ from the right-hand side to the left-hand side of the equation.

Comment: Thank a lot! I actually understood it.

Answer (score 2):

In the reference frame moving down, the ground is moving up. So the equation is not $$ 100\mathrm{\ m} = 1/2 \ (9.8 \mathrm{\ m/s^2}) \ t^2 $$ but rather $$ 100\mathrm{\ m} - (20\mathrm{\ m/s}) \ t = 1/2 \ (9.8 \mathrm{\ m/s^2}) \ t^2 $$

Comment: Yeah I get it now. That was kinda stupid. Thanks a lot.